# google analytics incoherent visits in custom report

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

in GA if I create a custom report filtered by a specific page or source/medium I see an incoherent number of visits, in particular unique visitors are higher than visits.
If I remove the filter visits become coherent with visitors and page views!

Answer (score 0):

> I found what I believe is the answer in the link below.
>
> http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2010/04/23/unique-visitors-0-visits-and-pages-in-web-analytics/
>
> To detail the answer is quite lengthy, but in summary - for purposes
>   of attribution, google credits a visit at the page level to the first
>   page visited in a single visit. However it credits every page viewed
>   to a unique visitor.
>
> So basically what the visit metric stands for in the report you showed
>   is how many visits started their visit on that page. To find out how
>   many actual VISITS went to a particular page use unique pageviews
>   since it counts pageviews only once, for every visit.
>
> Confusing...yes. However it appears to be the reason.

Source: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27276

Comment: So its a entrance visit! Thanks Tom